# Cannot Override CSS Mixin

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x, css-mixin

I'm developing RTL application uses the Arabic language so I want to change my application font to different font than Robot font, more specifically: `Noto Kufi Arabic`.

Looking to `paper-styles/typography.html` file, I expected to be able to change the used font by overriding `--paper-font-common-base` mixin inside my-element.

e.g.

```
<style>

:host { }

paper-tabs {
  --paper-font-common-base {
    font-family: 'Noto Kufi Arabic', sans-serif;
  };
}
</style>
```

However I can never get it to work this way!

The only which I was able to do is by commenting the below lines in  `paper-styles/typography.html`:

```
  --paper-font-common-base: {
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  };
```

and keep that mixin in `my-element` styles.

#### Expected

[image: expected outcome]

#### Actual

[image: actual outcome]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977706/changing-polymer-paper-elements-default-font.
 --paper-font-common-base isn't mixin of paper-tabs. That's why you can't change it

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský that's not correct, please see [`paper-tab`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/blob/2.0-preview/paper-tab.html#L60), also you can see [`paper-button`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-button/blob/2.0-preview/paper-button.html#L110), [`paper-input`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/2.0-preview/paper-input.html#L101) .... all of them apply --paper-font-common-base ...

Comment: Only paper-input applies `--paper-font-subhead` which in its turn applies `paper-font-common-base`.

Comment: still, paper-tabs don't use  --paper-font-common-base. Only paper-tab. but  it's different element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have forgotten the colons after the mixin name, that should give you an error in your code editor/IDE, at least in Visual Studio Code:

```
paper-tabs {
   --paper-font-common-base: {
       font-family: 'Noto Kufi Arabic', sans-serif;
   };
}
```